# Rails ActiveAdmin nearly duplicate code for columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'd like to figure out a way to not duplicate so much code with ActiveAdmin when creating and index and a CSV. For example:

```
index do
    column('Order Id', sortable: 'orders.number') {|oi| oi.order.number }
    column('Price', sortable: :price_cents) { |oi| oi.price.format }
    ...
end

csv do
  column('Order Id') {|oi| oi.order.number }
  column('Price') { |oi| oi.price.format }
  ...
end
```

Where the columns are essentially identical (with the exception of sortable). I tried pulling the column calls out into a method, but it appears since ActiveAdmin is a DSL that this doesn't work.

Any suggestions? Thanks.